# Array storage in SQLite

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I need to store a set of scores in integer (array of scores) for a player. How can I store an array in a single column? I'm using the SQLite database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please don't store multiple values in a single column, it makes for much harder queries.  You're best to put in another table with a foreign key back to your first table.

```
   Table 1
    playerID
    playerName

   Table 2
    scoreID
    playerID
    score
```

Add multiple rows into table 2 and have the playerID in the second table reference playerID in the first table.

Comment: Thanks Stimms, this is what I was looking for also, but to store long values (multiple dates)